# Force GMail to check mails from other accounts

Tags: email, gmail

I am using GMail to collect mails from other non-Google email accounts. It turned out that GMail uses its own rules to check new mails in these external accounts. This does not happen in real time or at least periodically with the required frequency (say, every 1 or 2 minutes). Even the Refresh button above the mail list does not help if I want to check mails manually. To nudge GMail to check emails in external accounts, I open its Settings (first `Quick Settings`, then `All settings`, then open the `Accounts and Import` tab, and finally click the `Check mail now` link in the `Check mail from other accounts:` section.

My questions:

1. Is there any setting that makes the Refresh button work for external accounts?
2. How to set the desired frequency of checking mails in external accounts from GMail?

Comment: Doubleclick the refresh button.

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60894372/gmail-check-mail-now-shortcut-for-external-accounts

Answer (score -3):

I recommend you to use the following simple & effective tool:
https://www.danielslaughter.com/project/gmailpop3/

Comment: Link-only answers are no good if the link dies. Please include important information in the answer.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1124848)

Comment: I didn't ask about third-party tools that depend on the browser.